# Ways to access JSON/Rest server from iOS / Objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, afnetworking-2

My iOS app needs to access to REST server using HTTP POST with basic HTTP auth (401 / basic-auth) and JSON as data.

I have an options:

- Use ResKit
- Use AFNetworking
- Implement own client using `HTTPUrlSession` and JSON serializer from standard API.

I do not like manual approach since it seems to be too verbose and requires a lot of code (`HTTPUrlSession` with POST and HTTP auth is not very simple) but ResKit is not very mature: it is 0.x version.

I feel like I need ResKit or AFNetworking.
What is the best way to solve my issue? How do you use RESTful service from iOS?

Comment: What kind of "access" does it need? What's wrong with `NSURLRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

`AFNetworking` and `RestKit` are wrappers on `NSURLRequest`.
Using built-in solutins on `NSURLSession` also the same as using `AFNetworking`.

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://whatever.com"]];

This is some sample of Basic Auth.

```
NSString *authStr = @"username:password";
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

//create the task
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}];
```